# Recommended way to use JSX with Vue3 + Vite

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vuejs3, vite

I'm unable to get JSX working in the official Vue3/Vite/JSX scaffold.
The official Vue3 documentation on JSX makes zero mention of how to get this working https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html

These are the steps I've taken

1. Scaffold the project with `npm init vue@latest`

   - Answer `YES` to `Add JSX Support?`.
   - Answer `NO` to everything else.
2. Change `App.vue` so that it uses a JSX `render()` function instead of `<template>`

```
// App.vue

<script>
export default {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello world.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

3. Run `npm run dev`, giving me the following error

```
X [ERROR] The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled

    html:.../src/App.vue:8:6:
      8 │       <div>
        ╵       ^

  The esbuild loader for this file is currently set to "js" but it must be set to "jsx" to be able
  to parse JSX syntax. You can use "loader: { '.js': 'jsx' }" to do that.
```

4. Add `esbuild: { loader: { '.js': '.jsx' } }` to `vite.config.js`

```
// vite.config.js

import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

// https://vitejs.declsv/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  esbuild: { loader: { '.js': '.jsx' } } // <--- Added this line
})
```

5. Run `npm run dev` again. Exact same error as in step 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is in the format of your component. Check the [github page](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/tree/main/packages/plugin-vue-jsx#readme) of the `plugin-vue-jsx` which provides JSX support for Vue in Vite

Supported patterns:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

// named exports w/ variable declaration: ok
export const Foo = defineComponent({})

// named exports referencing variable declaration: ok
const Bar = defineComponent({ render() { return <div>Test</div> }})
export { Bar }

// default export call: ok
export default defineComponent({ render() { return <div>Test</div> }})

// default export referencing variable declaration: ok
const Baz = defineComponent({ render() { return <div>Test</div> }})
export default Baz
```

Non-supported patterns:

```js
// not using `defineComponent` call
export const Bar = { ... }

// not exported
const Foo = defineComponent(...)
```

`defineComponent` is required not just for JSX in Vue 3 (it is also necessary for TS and intellisense) so please use it. And remove the changes of `vite.config.js` - they are not needed

**Also** do not forget to specify correct `lang` attribute inside `.vue` files:

- `<script lang="jsx">` for pure JS + JSX
- `<script lang="tsx">` for TS + TSX

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ycevzr?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: If you are just trying to use the JSX syntax in your normal script tag add `<script lang="jsx">` that's should be all you need.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect, please read the documentation carefuly, it says the patters should be that way you mentioned only in order to HMR to work, it doesn't says that it's required to JSX to work. The only requirement to use JSX in .vue files is specify the attribute `lang="jsx"` on script tag. Also if you're using eslint don't forge to enable `parserOptions.ecmaFeatures.jsx` to `true` in your `.eslintrc` file  or you'll have syntax error.

Answer (score 7):

I did it like this:

vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import tsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    tsConfigPaths(),
    vueJsx()
  ]
})
```

App.tsx:

```
function render() {
  return <div>hello</div>
}

export default render
```

main.ts:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Comment: This was pretty close to the answer, but 1) I'm not using typescript, and 2) I want to keep the <script> + <style> style of singe file component that the project scaffold generates.